# table pivot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert the table

| Time | Params | Values | Lot ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | A | 3 | a1 |
| t1 | B | 4 | a1 |
| t1 | C | 7 | a1 |
| t1 | D | 2 | a1 |
| t2 | A | 2 | a1 |
| t2 | B | 5 | a1 |
| t2 | C | 9 | a1 |
| t2 | D | 3 | a1 |
| t3 | A | 2 | a2 |
| t3 | B | 5 | a2 |
| t3 | C | 9 | a2 |
| t3 | D | 3 | a2 |

to

| Time | A | B | C | D | Lot ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 2 | a1 |
| t2 | 2 | 5 | 9 | 3 | a1 |
| t3 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 2 | a2 |

Tried

```
df.pivot(index = 'Time', columns = 'Params', values = 'Values')
```

but it didn't come out with **Lot ID**

How can I add that to the table as an additional column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` argument of `pivot` can take a list.

```py
df.pivot(index = ['Time', 'Lot ID'], columns = 'Params', values = 'Values')
```

Will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I kept trying to add that to column, but to index it worked!

Comment: You also might want to add a `.reset_index` after the `pivot` call. When using `pivot` with a list at `index` will result in a `MultiIndex DataFrame`